# AngulasJS Official Tutorial Step 2 Data not binding on refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I am following the angular phonecatApp tutorial and stuck on step 2. When I go to my index page: `http://localhost:8000/app/`

The data binding seems to not be working... This is what my view loads:

```
{{phone.name}}
{{phone.snippet}}
```

It should theoretically pull the data and bind it to the view and display the table right? Now sure why it's not working any idea? My code follows:

This is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
      <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my js/controllers/js

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
});
```

My console.log says:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module phonecatApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'phonecatApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/nomod?p0=phonecatApp
    at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
    at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1764:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1688:38)
    at module (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1762:14)
    at http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4094:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4078:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4004:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1446:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:8000/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1467:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=phonecatApp&p1=Erro…calhost%3A8000%2Fapp%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1467%3A12)
```

Comment: can you create a plunk?

Comment: @fauverism what is that?

Comment: @fauverism I have posted my console.log output here. It looks like some things are not loading do you know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is nothing wrong with your code, the problem must be that one of the scripts is not being loaded.

You can easily use the Development tools of most Browsers to be able to detect such problems.

Check if the path to the script files are correct.

Comment: I have paste my console.log browser error message. Not sure what it means I tried to npm install again but I still get the same error

Comment: Looks like controllers.js is not being loaded. Did you check if the path is correct? Can you click through to it from inspecting the source code in your browser?

Comment: yes its the correct path I am able to go to it on the source code link

Comment: Still, the problem must be in something you haven't posted. This works just fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/3h6DpnmYeeeCOtUGaF2z

Comment: Thanks, this was my mistake I was going to the wrong route... Really silly of my I figured the index would go to app/index but it was app/index.html